# Why I can't access to the paginator DTO in EasyAdmin?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I'm trying to access the `EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\PaginatorDto`in my Crud Controller :

```php
public function __construct(
        private EntityManagerInterface $manager,
        private EntityRepository $entityRepository,
        private PaginatorDto $paginatorDto,
    ) {
    }
```

But I've got this error => `Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\Activity\ActivityCrudController": argument "$paginatorDto" of method "__construct()" references class "EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\PaginatorDto" but no such service exists.` and I don't understand why and How to fix it :(

Any idea ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the paginator ? Could you specifiy ? Depending on what you want to do it may not even be needed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A DTO is usually a DTO, and not a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert of that bundle so take my answer with a pinch of salt but looking at bundle's code I've noticed `PaginatorDto` not to be a service (as the name suggests).

As that DTO is not a service (and it's ok it is not), you can't autowire it nor make it a service "locally" (eg.: in your application).

So, in order to retrieve the DTO object, inject `AdminContextProvider` (that is a service as you can notice [here](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/4.x/src/Resources/config/services.php#L144-L145)) instead and use it to get the DTO

```
$adminContext->getCrud()->getPaginator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your crud controller should extend `AbstractCrudController` which give you access to the current admin context.

So if you want to use it in one of your crud controller method you should be able to access the paginator with:

```
$paginator = $this->getContext()->getCrud()->getPaginator();
```

If you want to do the same outside your crud controller, let's say in another service. You need to inject the `AdminContextProvider` to first get the `AdminContext` and do it the same way.

```
private ?AdminContext $siteRepository;

public function __construct(AdminContextProvider $adminContextProvider)
{
    $this->adminContext = $adminContextProvider->getContext();
}
```